# Incorrect value of $.post. Selection in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have file delete.php witch contains

```
<?php
$folder = "./fak/";
$filename = $_POST['name'];
unlink($folder.$filename);   
?>
```

and index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function(){

      $.post("delete.php",
      {
        name:$(".delete").attr("value")
      },
      function(data, status){
        alert("data:"+ data + "\n Status:" + status)
        location.reload();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./fak/1.png">
    <button class="delete" value="1.png"> delete img </buttom>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="./fak/2.png">
    <button class="delete" value="2.png"> delete img </buttom>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my problem, no matter which button I insert delete.php remove 1.png. When I insert button once more jQuery alert that the file 1.png don't exist.

So my problem is in selection correct value and after execute php file clear value 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".delete").attr()` will retrun first always, replace with

```
   $(".delete").click(function(){
      $.post("delete.php",
      {
        name:$(this).attr("value")
      },
      function(data, status){
        alert("data:"+ data + "\n Status:" + status)
        location.reload();
      });
```